# Swift: Unable to make UIApplication conform to my protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, uiapplication

I'm trying to make UIApplication conform to the following protocol:

```
protocol URLOpenerProtocol {
    func open(_ url: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}
```

I've added the following extension:

```
extension UIApplication: URLOpenerProtocol {}
```

However, I am getting a conforming error.

Given the UIApplication already has the following method on it:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(_ url: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

why won't this conform? The two seem to be indentical to me...

Error is as follows:

> Type `UIApplication` does not conform to protocol `URLOpenerProtocol`

Comment: sure thing, added it now

Comment: You need to add func open(_ url: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?) in your extension.

Comment: But that function already exists for UIApplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `open` method in `UIApplication` is declared like this with 3 parameters, and the second and third ones happen to be optional ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open)):

```
func open(
    _ url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:],
    completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil
)
```

`UIApplication` has no two-parameter method with this signature:

```
func open(_ url: URL, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

It only has the three-parameter one. Therefore, it does not conform to your protocol.

You should add the `options` parameter into your protocol too, so that `UIApplication` can conform to it, and I would suggest that you add a protocol extension with the two-parameter version:

```
protocol URLOpenerProtocol {
    func open(_ url: URL,
              options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any],
              completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}

extension URLOpenerProtocol {
    func open(_ url: URL,
              completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, simple as that! Yup, had totally missed that it had those optional params. Thanks a lot